# How to retain leading zero while converting String to number?

Tags: java, android

I Have a String that contain number. But

```
String s = "01234";
Long val = Long.parseLong (s);
```

This will gives me the result **1234** instead of **01234** 
How to retain the initial zero?
Is there any methods?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think it's possible.

Comment: Why would you care? Mathematically, 1234 is defined as the number of elements in the set containing 0 to 1233. It only matters when you want to display the number, and for that you can use the formatters available in Java.

Comment: You can't, because a long does not have a leading zero.

Comment: That you can not do I think. But you can do it like keep it String when you need value with leading zero, and keep it long when you want to do mathematical operations.

Comment: @ShaileshYadav This particular Long has 53 leading binary zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot retain zero because Long can't have leading Zeroes.

For computers:

When you're assigning 0001, this isn't actually "0001", but 1 in octal (in this case, same as 1 in decimal).

An Long is an Long; "leading zeroes don't make a number special".

> IMPORTANT POINT: a leading "0" is a "literal octal". The literal "07"
>   is "7". The literal "010" is "8". The literal "08" is illegal.

But, however you can print the number with leading zeroes using java formatter capability (java.util.Formatter).

Working Code: http://ideone.com/4MGZyi

```
int arjun = 1234;
System.out.printf("%05d", arjun);
```

%03d => add zero at start + result 5 character long + input will be a long

Comment: Hey i m not casting it back to string i need to retain it only in Long format

Comment: Why do you need it bro!!

Comment: Fine , I just resolved by taking the length but this is not the proper way

Comment: What did you want to achieve ? I am still puzzled. But, u did hit a nail with that question.

Comment: A verification step,  fine sir

Comment: Yeah do you have any other suggestion better than this

Comment: The number you checking is it entered by user or you are taking a form input through a service call.

Comment: Its on Service call

Comment: I would use regular expression then. String regex = "\\d+";

// positive test cases, should all be "true"
System.out.println("1".matches(regex));
System.out.println("12345".matches(regex));
System.out.println("123456789".matches(regex));

Comment: This particular `Long` has 53 leading binary zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't give you `1234`. It gives you a 64-bit binary value that can be represented as `0b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010011010010`, including all those leading zero bits, and something *else* in your code subsequently *prints* that as `1234`.

The place to fix this is not in the code you posted but in the printing code, by using `DecimalFormat`.